# Updating date in table throwing exception

Tags: java, oracle

I am executing this below query

```
  update ttt_table set 
  UPDATEDDATE = To_Date('03.03.03 14:29:34.337') WHERE NAME='SSSAAWW';
```

and it is showing the error `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Comment: Did you look up the docs to find why `ORA-01843`? http://ora-01843.ora-code.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you want hundredths of a second you have to use TO_TIMESTAMP function.

```
update ttt_table set 
UPDATEDDATE = To_Timestamp('03.03.03 14:29:34', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') WHERE NAME='SSSAAWW';
```

TO_DATE would look as follows:

```
update ttt_table set 
UPDATEDDATE = To_Date('03.03.03 14:29:34', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') WHERE NAME='SSSAAWW';
```

Answer (score 1):

try to define the format of the date string

```
update ttt_table 
set UPDATEDDATE = To_Date('03.03.03 14:29:34', 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') WHERE NAME='SSSAAWW';
```

Comment: to_date('03.03.03 14:29:34.337', 'yy.mm.dd HH24:MI:SS.FF3')

Answer (score 1):

Change the To_Date method like this

eg: to_date('2003/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd');

in your case : to_date('03.03.03 14:29:34.337', 'yy.mm.dd HH24:MI:SS.FF3')

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your case:

```
update ttt_table set 
UPDATEDDATE = To_Timestamp('03.03.03 14:29:34', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') WHERE NAME='SSSAAWW';
```